# Is MSXML4 thread safe?

Tags: xml, msxml

I would like to know if I create an instance of Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.4.0 in one thread, can I safely manipulate the instance from different threads using raw pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  That is the point of the FreeThreadedDOMDocument.

cite: [IXMLDOMDocument/DOMDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987(VS.85).aspx)

> If you are writing a single threaded
>   application (or a multi-threaded
>   application where only one thread
>   accesses a DOM at one time), then you
>   should use the rental threaded model
>   (Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0,
>   Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0, or
>   Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0). If you are
>   writing an application where multiple
>   threads access will simultaneously
>   access a DOM, then you should use the
>   free threaded model
>   (Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0,
>   Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.4.0, or
>   Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0).